# Api Key authentication in .NET 6 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to create Web Api that allows both JWT and Api key based authorization and authentication.

JWT authorization works really well for example header:

`Authorization | Bearer ds2dsa.......`

But I can't force it to work with an example GUID based Api Key:

`Authorization | 72f0bf91-2238-4e70-827e-af0e60c81991` - returns 401 - Unauthorized.

My `Startup.cs` look's like this:

```cs
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
/// some validation parameters here
                    };
                });
```

and below I have:

```cs
            app.UseCors(ourOrigins);

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMiddleware<PatAuthenticationMiddleware>();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

Where my `PatAuthenticationMiddleware` looks like this:

```cs
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Extract the token from the Authorization header
        string authorizationHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader) && !authorizationHeader.StartsWith("Bearer ")) // we got PAT
        {

            // Authenticate using PAT if provided
            string token = authorizationHeader.Trim();

            if (IsValidPat(token))
            {
                if (context.User is not null)
                {
                    // query db to get user info based on PAT
                    var claims = await _authService.GetClaimsForPat(Guid.Parse(token));
                    if (claims is null) goto Skip;
                    var claimsToInclude = new List<Claim> {
                        // additional claims here
                    }
                    var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimsToInclude);
                    context.User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                    // assign claims

                    // Check if the user has the required claim(s) for authorization
                    var authorizationResult = await _authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(context.User, null, "PatAuthorization");

                    if (!authorizationResult.Succeeded)
                    {
                        // User is not authorized based on the policy
                        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Skip:
        // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
        await _next(context);
    }
```

I knew there is something like `aspnetcore-authentication-apikey` nuget package but when I included it into `services.AddAuthentication` I was still getting 401

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I forgot to add - key is validated successfully

Comment: You mention  x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  So the framework will try to check if the token is fulfilling these conditions. In your case a GUID based Api Key will not so that is why you get the 401.

Comment: I'm not seeing the part where you're adding API key authentication as a part of the authentication flow?